# Add Web form input to an Array

Tags: php, arrays

I cannot figure out how to go about keeping the data saved on $myArray after hitting Save. Everytime i do that, it replaces the other input.

I need to be able to save all user enters and save in text file. basically keep saving data on array and update file as well.

Any suggestions?

```
<!DOCTYPE>
        <html>
        <body>
            <form action="list.php" method="POST">
            Name: <input type="text" name="name[]" /><br />
            Email: <input type="text" name="name[]" /><br />
           <input type="submit" name="save" value="Submit" /><br />
        <?php
            $myArray = array();

        if (isset($_POST['save']))
        {
            array_push($myArray,$_POST['name']);
        }

        print_r($myArray);
        ?>
        </body>
        </html>
```

Comment: `$_POST` is already an array. Why are you adding them to another array?

Comment: Because its not saving the previous data entered in the web form. so lets say for example, I entered Name and email and clicked Submit. it goes to the array but when i entered another name it replaces the previous one.

Comment: HTML / PHP is purely transactional. Each time you press `submit` it starts over with new values for everything. The only way to do it is to either save it in the `$_SESSION` or keep writing it to the file and read the whole thing from the file each time.

Comment: You're re-writing the `$_POST` array each time, and you will re-write your array each time. the results will never be cumulative.

Answer (score 0):

Every time your user hits Submit, there is a new request sent to your script.
The variable `$myArray` is created on the first line of your PHP code, and is an empty array.

Variables do not persist across requests. I suggest you use either a cookie, or a session variable for this.

Example of the latter is here:

```
<?php
session_start(); // This has to be done before any data is sent to the client
session_regenerate_id(); // Good practice to prevent session hijacking
?>
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
<body>
    <form action="list.php" method="POST">
    Name: <input type="text" name="name[]" /><br />
    Email: <input type="text" name="name[]" /><br />
    <input type="submit" name="save" value="Submit" /><br />
    <?php
        if( !isset( $_SESSION['myArray'] ) || !is_array( $_SESSION['myArray'] ) )
        {
            $_SESSION['myArray'] = array();
        }
        if (isset($_POST['save']))
        {
            $_SESSION['myArray'][] = $_POST['name'];
        }
        print_r($_SESSION['myArray']);
        // Here you can write the contents of $_SESSION['myArray'] to a file.
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This way you will keep track of it in the text file:

```
    <html>
    <body>
        <form action="list.php" method="POST">
        Name: <input type="text" name="name[]" /><br />
        Email: <input type="text" name="name[]" /><br />
       <input type="submit" name="save" value="Submit" /><br />
    <?php
        $myArray = array();

    if (isset($_POST['save']))
    {
        $f = file_get_contents("myfile.txt");
        $myArray = split($f, "\n");
        array_push($myArray,$_POST['name']);
        file_put_contents("myfile.txt", implode($myArray, "\n"));
    }

    print_r($myArray);
    ?>
    </body>
    </html>
```

(You may want to use PHP_EOL [or whatever that constant is - I always have to look it up] in place of "\n")

Since HTML is by nature transactional you do not keep track of ANYTHING except sessions, databases, files - any variables you have start over empty each time you load your page again.

Comment: PHP_EOL is correct. Easy to remember: PHP_E(nd)O(f)L(ine)

Comment: Yea, it's the EOL_PHP, PHPEOL, etc permutations that get me mixed up.